# 'Keywords' under SO Careers search jobs are missing very common tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

The main page of [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) site displays the popular technologies next to '**Keywords**' label. I noticed it changes upon refresh (at least on first few reloads). I tried it in Safari and FF browsers and got different set of 'Keywords'. Here are the screenshots:

Chrome screenshot:

> [image]

Firefox screenshot: (just showing 'Keywords')

> [image]

Safari screenshot: (just showing 'Keywords')

> [image]

As you can see I got different sets of 'Keywords' for the popular technologies (few repeating). So, I'm curious to know if there any specific algorithm or criteria is used while picking these 'Keywords'. Is it based on the popular technologies from Stack Overflow [survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech) or the most tagged keywords on SO? or just random. Can anyone please explain this.

If not based on the survey, can it please be changed to take common tags from there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing so fancy I'm afraid. It's currently a static array of a bunch of tags and we take a random selection of 9 of them to show on the home page!

**Update:** Alex just added a bunch of tags from the 2015 Developer Survey, so things look a bit more current :)

Comment: Source code or it never happened. ;)

Comment: Thanks for confirming it and I will accept your answer. Would you mind checking if the static array has 'Javascript' in it as I have yet to see it under the 'Keywords'. The pop tech [survey](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech) shows it's the most-used programming language for the past 3 years in row.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 'Source Code'? but SO is not open-source

Comment: @HackerKarma Funnily enough it doesn't. I'll add a note to our bug duty board, it can be added. Or we can feed the list from SO tags or something.

Comment: @Hack http://i.stack.imgur.com/LbHFV.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was so focused on the serious part and missed it. Thanks. But Dean Ward confirmation about missing 'Javascript' is the proof.

Comment: Yay! I see my [Javascript tag](http://i.imgur.com/K5sCrU7.png) Thank you and Alex too.